# sample size impact on type 1 and type 2 errors

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Is there an equation that shows when more data results in a greater increase in the likelihood of a Type II error than a decrease in the likelihood of a Type I error

Answer (score 1):

At any given sample size, you can set type I error or type II.  Increasing one decreases the other. Higher sample size will (in general) decrease both. But there's no general formula - there's an entire field of power analysis designed to deal with these issues.

Comment: Type I error is a function of your a priori alpha level (e.g., .05 or .01) and is not a function of sample size. Having a larger sample size does not increase or decrease the Type I error, assuming a constant alpha level. However, the likelihood of a Type II error decreases as sample size increases, all other things being equal (i.e., the alpha level and the size of the true population effect).